# Switching between open windows by mouse wheel

Tags: windows-7, windows

In opera browser you can hold down mouse right button and rotate its wheel to select a tab. Is there any tool that provide similar functionality for windows?

Comment: if you have a mouse driver that allows you to assign detailed macros, that could be a way. Win+Tab is the aero version of Alt+Tab and it allows for selection by mousewheel. So if you assign Win+Tab to another mousebutton in a way that Tab is tapped but Win is held, then you should have the functionality you are looking for at least for "a mouse button".

Comment: @TheUser1024 Win+Tab is terrible I just use Alt+Tab!

Comment: Yeah, me too, but the mouse wheel doesn't do anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher/new-alt-tab.html#mouse) offers something close enough to what you what:

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks, It is not close to what I want, it's exactly what I was looking for, also I that site I also found some other very useful app too. Thanks

Comment: Good to know it helped! :)